# send email to local directory instead of mailserver

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtpclient, smtplib

I have written a python piece of code to send email using SMTP.

I have used smtplib. It's working fine.

I want to simulate a scenario where many users would send email. So to avoid overloading the server I want that message should not be stored on mail server. Instead they should be stored in a local directory. But the mail server should be hit.

How can go about doing this in python. This is what I have written

```
SMTP_SERVER = 'mailserver.com'
now = datetime.now()
SMTP_PORT = 25
sender = "test1@test.com"
recipient = "test2@test.com"
subject = "Test Subject"
Body = "This is a test messages"
day = now.strftime('%a')
date = now.strftime('%d %b %Y %X')
Headers = ["From: "+sender, "Subject: "+subject, "To:"+recipient,"MIME-Version: 1.0", "Content-Type: text/html", "Date: "+day+','+date]
Headers = "\r\n".join(Headers)
session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo()
session.sendmail(sender,recipient, Headers +"\r\n\r\n" + Body)
```

Comment: How can you "hit" the mail server but at the same time avoid overloading it ?

Comment: how do you make the message, with the email package?

Comment: I need to simulate the scenario of email sending, but at the same time I do not want to store message on server